# CSS Href Link not working

Tags: html

I have a HTML and CSS but the href link is not working:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <h3 class="dropbtn">{{::options.title}}&nbsp&nbsp<span class="caret"></span></h3>
  <span class="text-muted">{{::options.short_description}}</span>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a title="Hardware" target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Hardware </a></li>
    <a title="Hardware" target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Software </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

href is not taking me to google.com 
Pls help

Comment: Kinda ironic, because Google could've helped you to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit 'http://' from the beginning of the href attribute, it treats it as a relative link. Use something like 'https://www.google.com/'